# data type mismatch in criteria expression vb.net access

Tags: odbc, mongodb-.net-driver, pyodbc, unixodbc, jdbc-odbc

This My Code

Public Function simpan() As Integer
        Dim sql As String
        Dim cmmd As OleDbCommand

```
    sql = "INSERT INTO disposisi    (nodisposisi,noagendamasuk,idseksi,intruksi,tgldisposisi,nosurat,perihal,nama)" & _
    "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    cmmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cnn)
    cmmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nodisposisi", FNoDisposisi)
    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("noagendamasuk", FAgenda)
    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("idseksi", FIdSeksi)
    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("intruksi", FIntruksi)
    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tgldisposisi", FTgl)
    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nosurat", FNoSrt)
    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("perihal", FPerihal)
    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nama", FNama)

    Return cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Function
```

I don't know what i do please help me

Comment: What is the specific problem that you're having?

Answer (score 0):

probably the data type you are trying to insert in table is not what that column is expecting

like you are inserting char in int column .you need to check table definition.You have to

look at the Databases's expected datatype to know for sure